# Foreign Key Error 1215

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Trying to create a foreign key on table Supplier for Supplier_ID referencing table Payment.

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
Supplier_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Amount INT (4), 
Payment_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID, Supplier_ID)
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
Supplier_ID INT(4) NOT NULL,    
Name VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
Reliability_Score INT(4),
Contact_Info VARCHAR(4), 
PRIMARY KEY (Supplier_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Payment(Supplier_ID) 
);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key has to reference a unique column. So the `Supplier_ID` column needs to be unique.

However, it seems like you might have it backward if I'm understanding your intention correctly. It should probably be a foreign key on supplier_ID in the Payment table referencing the supplier table.

Answer (score -2):

In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table. In other words, a foreign key is a column or a combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables.

in your code u have declared primary key as `PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID, Supplier_ID)` which is a combination of two columns which is totally fine but while creating foreign key `FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Payment(Supplier_ID)` you are referring one column to a combination of two columns which is wrong

read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Key

**now your solution:**
first create Supplier table

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier (
Supplier_ID INT(4) NOT NULL,    
Name VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
Reliability_Score INT(4),
Contact_Info VARCHAR(4), 
PRIMARY KEY (Supplier_ID)
);
```

now the payment table

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
Supplier_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Amount INT (4), 
Payment_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID, Supplier_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Supplier(Supplier_ID)
);
```